# os.listdir reads images randomly making bounding box training difficult

Tags: keras

os.listdir(path) command reads images randomly from a folder. I have saved a csv file with bouding box information for the images in folder sequentially. I assumed os.listdir would read the images sequentially so that my csv file also can be read sequentiallu during the training.

I have tried sorted(os.listdir) but no use. I could not find any other functions or code to read the images sequentially from a folder. I named the images as frame1.jpg, frame2.jpg etc.

```
PATH = os.getcwd()
# Define data path
data_path = PATH + '/frames'
data_dir_list = sorted(os.listdir(data_path))
print(data_dir_list)
img_data_list=[]

for dataset in (data_dir_list):
    img_list=sorted(os.listdir(data_path+'/'+ dataset))
    print ('Loaded the images of dataset-'+'{}\n'.format(dataset))
    for img in sorted(img_list):
        input_img=cv2.imread(data_path + '/'+ dataset + '/'+ img )
        input_img=cv2.cvtColor(input_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        input_img1=input_img
        #input_img_resize=cv2.resize(input_img,(512,512))
        img_data_list.append(input_img1)

img_data = np.array(img_data_list)
img_data = img_data.astype('float32')
img_data /= 255
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Python docs, `os.listdir()` returns filenames in an arbitrary order. It just maps to an underlying operating system call that will return filenames in whatever order is presumably most efficient based on filesystem design.

It's just a standard list of strings, so `sorted()` would work in the way you're using it. Are the sequential numbers in your filenames correctly padded for this to work with the more than 10 images you're presumably using? What's the random order you're seeing from `sorted(os.listdir(...))`?

Comment: I am working with 500 images and all the frames are mostly similar it is difficult for me to find the order. i named my images as frame1, frame2, frame3,.......frame500. As i mentioned 'sorted' is not working. Is there any other method possible? Is there any image naming convention that will help?

Comment: @Ethan If you sort a frame1, frame2, frame3 .... frame500 alphabetically then you'll end up with a frame100 before frame2. You will either need to pad the sequential number in your filename so that it's frame001, frame002, frame003 ... frame500 or tell `sorted` what value to sort with. 

With your filenames as they are, you could extract the number from the filename and ask sorted to use that instead like this `sorted(os.listdir(...), key=lambda fn: int(fn.split('.')[0][len('frame'):]))`

Comment: Thanks a ton...changing the frame name to frame001 etc sorted out the problem. Can you tell me how frame100 is picked up before frame2? Also "sorted(os.listdir(...), key=lambda fn: int(fn.split('.')[0][len('frame'):])) " didnt work

Comment: It's sorting two strings so it will look at each character of the string, so it will sort on the first character of the number first i.e. the 1 in 100 will always come before a 2.  What doesn't work about my code? You have to be more specific for me understand what is wrong with how you're using it or if there's a typo somewhere

Comment: once i stored the frames as frames001, frame002 etc sorted worked. But I tried using the sorted function format you mentioned above. That did not work. I will check it again and update you. And thank you very much for the suggestion on saving the frames as frame001 etc. It helped and i could run the code successfully.